# How can I create an alias name for a model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, alias

I have an application where users created 'boards'

I have had to change the name of the website and now users create 'walls'.

Currently I have the following url's:

```
   http://mysite.com/boards
   http://mysite.com/boards/i/edit
```

Is there a way to alias the name 'boards' to 'walls' so my URL's will be as follows:

```
http://mysite.com/walls
http://mysite.com/walls/1/edit
```

etc without having to change the name of the table, models, and code?

routes.rb

resources :boards

I would also like to alias the paths if possible:

new_board_path would still be valid even if resources are written as follows:

resources :walls, :controller => :boards

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
resources :walls, :controller => :boards
```

Comment: I tried that but I get an error => No route matches "/walls/1"

Comment: That works but then I have to change all of the paths as in new_board_path to new_wall_path. Or is there a way to alias this as well

Comment: Is that because you've removed the line like resources :boards ?

Comment: Right.  So I still have to change all of the urls from boards to walls right?

Comment: Hmmmm, yeah.  I was imagining you'd leave the original resource in and this was just an alias.  I'm afraid I don't know how to fix it if you need the original resource name to be gone.